SwiftUI disable simultaneous gesture
I have an app that needs audio input, and the button gesture needs to recognize long press.
The View is like
VStack {
    ScrollView
    InputButton
}

The gesture modify is
        .highPriorityGesture(
            LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.01, maximumDistance: 200)
                .sequenced(before: DragGesture(minimumDistance: .zero, coordinateSpace: .global))
                .updating($pressState, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                    switch value {
                    case .first(true):
                        // start press
                   
                    case .second(true, let drag):
                        state = .started
                        if let drag = drag {
                           //Calculate drag
                        }
                        break
                    default:
                        state = .inactive
                        // on end
                    }
                })
                .onEnded({ value in
                    // on end
                }),
            including: .gesture
        )

The gesture works when normally used, but if I press the button while scrolling, the LongPress won't detect the end event and the drag position is wrong.
How can I cancel any other gesture when I start this gesture?
Many thanks
